# how to get image path from ionic web application and upload image from Browser

Tags: angular, web-applications, ionic3

Hi i'm developing `Hybrid` web app using `ionic-3`. i want to choose image and `upload` from web app but i have no idea how to select file from web. Can anybody suggest me how to upload image from web using ionic 3.

i have tried below method but i'm getting fake path.

> upload.html

```
<ion-content>
<form [formGroup]="file" (ngSubmit)="logForm()">
    <input type="file" size="50" formControlName="image">
    <button ion-button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
</ion-content>
```

> upload.ts

```
   import { Component } from '@angular/core';
    import {Validators, FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
    import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-upload',
  templateUrl: 'upload.html',
})
export class UploadPage {
  private file : FormGroup;
  profile_img: string;
  form: FormGroup;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
      this.file = this.formBuilder.group({
        image: ['']
    });
  }
      logForm(){
        console.log(this.file)
    }

}
```

> output of above code is as like below image

[image]

thank you.